# R Shiny Horizontal Reactive Axis Labels

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I have the following code in R shiny that creates a graph with reactive labels. The y labels are the choice name (not value) of the user input however they are currently being displayed vertically whereas I need them horizontal.

```
output$colm <- (renderPlot({barplot(
  as.numeric(input$vars),
  beside = TRUE,
  main = "Gap Analysis",
  xlab = "Mean Difference",
  horiz = TRUE,
  xlim = c(-1, 1),
  ylim = c(0, 5),
  ylab = names(gapChoices[input$vars == gapChoices]),
  col = cols,
  las = 1)}))
```

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the code directly on the side rather than using images.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
las = 1
```

That should work. Are you getting any errors when plotting? You may need to use

```
par(las=1)
```